# Make existing form-login application also serve as an oauth2 authorization server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

We had an web application that already using form-login provided by spring-security, say, ERP. Now we are considering make ERP as an oauth2 authorization server to authorize other internal services.

The ERP still serving its business and all access are required to be authorized, but doesn't based on access token so I think it is not an oauth2 client. It does NOT serve as an Resource Server, neither.

I have read many article about how to setup oauth2 authorization server and develop an application using it. According to [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/149#issuecomment-355116521) I feel it is possible to make ERP authorizing other services without explicit setup a standalone authorization server (it's our final goal but not now):

> Within the context of OAuth2, we can break things up according to the component you're implementing:
>
> - Client app: it's likely that server based OAuth2 Client app already uses HttpSession and therefore it makes sense to use Spring Session and benefit from all the goodies it brings
> - Resource Server app: since this component provides a stateless API that's authenticated against using an Access Token as a bearer, the HttpSession is not used and therefore Spring Session isn't suitable as well
> - Authorization Server app: it's highly likely that this already uses HttpSession so similarly like with OAuth2 Client app, it makes sense to use Spring Session and benefit from all the goodies it brings

What I'm going to do is add the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` into config, but I have no idea what's the next step.
My question is can I convert an existing application into an authorization server while keeping its original service unchanged? Where and How should I start?

Answer (score 0):

I just found it's not that hard to integrate OAuth2 into existing system, below is what I did to make it work.

In short: `EnableAuthorizationServer` won't break anything exists, but they don't coming from nothing, either.

When I put on the `EnableAuthorizationServer`, spring-security-oauth2 gives me following endpoing:

- `/oauth/authorize`
- `/oauth/check_token`
- `/oauth/token`
- `/oauth/confirm_access`
- `/oauth/error`

Those endpoints provide necessary functions to make OAuth2 works, and I just need to apply access control onto those endpoints with existing form login mechanism (probable not the `check_token` one).

Since this system didn't act as resource-server role, the authorization part is done.